# row context not filtering as expected in a 1 to many relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this going on with two separate relationships but for the sake of this question we will focus on one.

I have a Fact table full of a given services info and a separate region lookup table

[image: TCFPA_0-1672437757956.png]

There are only six regions and IDs. The job table has a Job ID which is correlated to a specific region

i.e., Job-2000 is region 1000

I would expect that when I add the JobID and the region name, I would get

Job-2000 LA West

However, that is not happening when I test a count on the data in the matrix one region ID is returning multiple region names

[image]

I am unsure why this is, as the region_key are all distinct

[image]

So for example

[image: TCFPA_4-1672438251982.png]

this job despite having one region ID it is getting a count of 6 regions

I'd instead expect the following

```
JobName     RegionID                                     Region Name
Job-0069    00038329-ac05-4f61-897a-e2ec7924a8f3    Olive Plaza Pilot
```

When I select the RegionID, I pull it from the Fact table and not the regions lookup table

What could be happening?

Comment: Filters always propagate from 1 to many side of relations. You are trying to do the opposite - you attempt to filter table on the "1"side by the field on the many side.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another copy of your region table that isn't related to your fact?